# Getting proxy list from url in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I use the roatating_proxies middleware in Scrapy and I want to use a url with all my proxies. The problem is that there are protected by a pseudo and a password.

The code in the "setting.py" file:

```
def getProxyList():
    resp = requests.get('http://api.buyproxies.org/etc')
    return resp.text.split()

ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = getProxyList()
```

The URL:

```
176.0.0.0:user:pswd
192.0.0.0:12345:user:pswd
45.0.0.0:12345:user:pswd
196.0.0.0:12345:user:pswd
151.0.0.0:12345:user:pswd
```

The error:

```
raise ValueError(message) from None
ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as '12345:user:pswd'
```

Comment: I don’t think https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies supports per-proxy usernames and passwords at the moment. You could fork it to implement that support. Or, if the username and password are always the same, you could strip them from the proxy strings and set them in your spider.

Comment: Arf... Okay, I'll try this instead, thank you